# NextJS React, nested array in UseState not rendering on update inside of javascript

Tags: reactjs, next.js, use-state

I have a hard time trying to understand "useState" and when a render is triggered. I want to make a drag and drop system where the user can drag elements from one box to another.

I have successfully done this by using pure javascript, but as usual, it gets messy fast and I want to keep it clean. I thought since I'm using react I should do it using UseState, and I've got the array to update the way I want it to but the changes don't render.

Shouldn't I use useState in this way? What should I use instead? I don't want to solve it the "hacky" way, I want it to be proper.

```
    const [allComponents, updateArray] = useState([])
 
    function arrayMove(array, closest) {
        let moveChild = array[parentIndex].children[childIndex]
        array[parentIndex].children = array[parentIndex].children.filter(function(value, index, arr){ return index != childIndex;});
        array[closest].children = [...array[closest].children, moveChild];
        return array;
    }

    var lastClosest = {"parent": null, "child": null};
    var parentIndex = null;
    var childIndex = null;

    function allowDrop(ev, index) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        if(allComponents.length > 0) {
            let closest = index;
            if((parentIndex == lastClosest.parent && childIndex == lastClosest.child) || (closest == parentIndex)) {
                return;
            }
            lastClosest.parent = parentIndex;
            lastClosest.child = childIndex;
            updateArray(prevItems => (arrayMove(prevItems, closest)));
        }
    }
    
    function dragStart(pI, cI, ev) {
        parentIndex = pI;
        childIndex = cI;
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function addNewSpace() {
        updateArray(prevItems => [...prevItems, {"name": "blaab", "children": [{"child": "sdaasd", "type": "text"}]}]);
    }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
        <button onClick={addNewSpace}>Add</button>
        <div className={styles.spacesWrapper}>
        {allComponents.map(({name, children}, index) => (
            <div key={"spacer_" + index} onDragOver={(event) => allowDrop(event, index)} onDrop={(event) => drop(event)} className={styles.space}>
                {children.map(({type, child}, index2) => (
                    <div id ={"movable_" + index + ":" + index2} key={"movable_" + index2} className={styles.moveableOne}>
                        <div key={"draggable_" + index2} draggable="true" onDrag={(event) => onDrag(event)} onDragStart={(event) => dragStart(index, index2, event)}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the problem I'm experiencing with the nested array not updating properly:
[image]

Comment: where is your useState hook and where does these values "allComponents" come from ?

Comment: @AppCity Sorry apperantly I missed to paste in my state hook, I will fix it immediately.  ."allComponent" values are added in the function "addNewSpace()" which is called when the button is clicked. This actually re-renders the page and a new space shows up.

Answer (score 0):

A react page re-renders every time the state changes. So every time a setState is called, the react component re-renders itself and updates the page to reflect the changes.

You can also see how the state is updating if you install the react dev tools chrome extension.

Comment: Is it just a problem with nested arrays then? Cause adding new elements to the primary array seems to work but when I edit/add elements to the nested array it doesn't re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code with the below code and see if it solves your issue,

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


let newAllComponents = [...allComponents];

  useEffect(() => 
  {
    newAllComponents = [...allComponents]
  }, [allComponents]);


/* div inside return*/
{newAllComponents.map(({ name, children }, index) => (
          <div
            key={"spacer_" + index}
            onDragOver={(event) => allowDrop(event, index)}
            onDrop={(event) => drop(event)}
          >
```

Comment: This has the exact same behavior. When the primary array is updated it renders the changes but when I update the nested array, nothing happens. To clarify: This works but when I do another map inside the "newAllComponents.map" for the "children" array. That does not render until I press the "Add" button again.

Comment: To solve this in a easier way, and avoid all the heavy lifting, you can also try "use-deep-compare-effect" instead of useEffect, so you can compare the nested children and rerender.
https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect

Comment: Just replacing my "useEffect" with "useDeepCompareEffect" did not solve the problem. Do I need to add any other dependency than "allComponents"?

Comment: Please check the example from the docs they provided, you need to pass the children name or id which changes inside the parent array